# A proof of J.L. Lions' Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I started a study on the Navier Stokes equations and my supervisor gave me a first result to work on which is the J.L. Lions Lemma which basically states the following:

> If $f\in H^{-1}(\Omega)$ and $\nabla f\in H^{-1}(\Omega)$. Then $f\in L^2(\Omega)$

My supervisor told me that since $\Omega$ is a Lipschitz domain and from the proof of the Global approximation by functions smooth up to the boundary theorem and its Evans's Partial Differential Equations:

> [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

making the convolution of $f\in H^{-1}(\Omega)\, \nabla f\in H^{-1}(\Omega)$, we are in $L^2$. We can then use the Necas inequality.

**My ideas:**

> - I think that the step 1 and 2 of proof is for build the open covers $\{V_i\}_{i=0}^{q}$ where $V_i=\Omega\cap B(x_0,\frac{r_i}{2})$ and we can choose $\Omega = \cup_{i=0}^q V_i$.
> - We can also take a classic regularizing sequence $(\rho_n)$ for $\epsilon>0$, let $\eta_\epsilon = \rho_{[1/\epsilon]+1}$ or again $f_\epsilon(x) = f(x^\epsilon) = f(x+\lambda\epsilon e_n)$ and I can take $$g_\epsilon = \eta_\epsilon * f_\epsilon.$$
>   I think it must be proven that $g_\epsilon \in L^2(V_i)$ and with that we can later use the Necas' inequality
> - Then, we seek to provide hypotheses to ensure the existence of the unit partition $\theta_0,\,\theta_2\,...\,\theta_q$ associated with the open cover $\{V_i\}$ and we take $h = \theta_i g_\epsilon$ and then prove that (by Necas' inequality) $$\|h\|_{L^2(\Omega)} = \|h\|_{L^2(V_i)}\leq C(\|g_\epsilon\|_{H^{-1}(\Omega)}+\|\nabla g_\epsilon\|_{H^{-1}(\Omega)}),$$
>   and passing to the limit when $\epsilon \rightarrow 0 $ we would get $$\|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq C(\|f\|_{H^{-1}(\Omega)}+\|\nabla f\|_{H^{-1}(\Omega)})<\infty.$$ We can conclude that $f\in L^2(\Omega)$

Any indications or suggestions are welcome

Comment: What precisely is the Necas inequality you are refering to ?

Comment: @daw Necas inequality that I'm refering is: $\exists C>0$ s.t if $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ then $\|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq C(\|f\|_{H^{-1}(\Omega)}+\|\nabla f\|_{H^{-1}(\Omega)})$

Comment: 'Actually' doesn't mean 'actuellement' or 'attualmente' or 'actualmente'...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The approximation argument is a lot simpler than you might think; for negative order spaces the zero extension $H^{-1}(\Omega) \hookrightarrow H^{-1}(\Bbb R^n)$ is continuous, so you you can simply extend by zero and mollify.

The key ingredient is the estimate
$$ \lVert g \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq C \left( \lVert g \rVert_{H^{-1}(\Omega)} + \lVert \nabla g \rVert_{H^{-1}(\Omega)}\right) $$
you mention in the comments, which is valid for $g \in L^2(\Omega).$ This is where one needs $\Omega$ to be a Lipschitz domain, as the proof I involves using Fourier analysis in the full space and the continuity of the restriction $H^{-1}(\Bbb R^n) \to H^{-1}(\Omega),$ and the latter is where one needs some regularity of the boundary. From here the strategy as you noted is to regularise $f,$ apply the above, and conclude by passing to the limit. For this we need the following.

**Lemma**: If $g \in H^{-1}(\Omega),$ extending by zero let $g_{\varepsilon} = g \ast \rho_{\varepsilon}$ where $\rho_{\varepsilon}$ is a standard mollifier. Then $g_{\varepsilon} \in C^{\infty}(\overline\Omega)$ and $g_{\varepsilon} \to g$ in $H^{-1}(\Omega).$

*Proof*: Since $g \in H^{-1}(\Omega),$ there exists $g_0,g_1,\dots,g_n \in L^2(\Omega)$ such that $g = g_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n D^ig_i.$ Then extending each $g_i$ by zero to $\Bbb R^n$ we have
$$ g_{\varepsilon} = g_0 \ast \rho_{\varepsilon} + \sum_{i=1}^n D^i(g_i \ast \rho_{\varepsilon}) $$
which is smooth on $\overline\Omega.$ Now we can estimate
$$ \lVert g-g_{\varepsilon} \rVert_{H^{-1}(\Omega)} \leq \sum_{i=0}^n \lVert g_i \ast \rho_{\varepsilon} - g_i \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)} \to 0 $$
as $\varepsilon \to 0,$ which proves the lemma.

Now the rest is straightforward; since $f_{\varepsilon} = f \ast \rho_{\varepsilon} \in C^{\infty}(\overline\Omega) \subset L^2(\Omega)$ we can apply Necas' inequality to get
\begin{align*}
   \liminf_{\varepsilon \to \infty}\lVert f_{\varepsilon} \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)} &\leq \lim_{\varepsilon \to \infty}C \left( \lVert f_{\varepsilon} \rVert_{H^{-1}(\Omega)} + \lVert \nabla f_{\varepsilon} \rVert_{H^{-1}(\Omega)}\right) \\
& = C \left( \lVert f \rVert_{H^{-1}(\Omega)} + \lVert \nabla f \rVert_{H^{-1}(\Omega)}\right) < \infty,
\end{align*}
so by Fatou's lemma we conclude that $f \in L^2(\Omega).$

Comment: Within the proof we don't need to use the partition of unity ?  And I think that one would regularize each convolution $θ_i f$ by with suitable regularizing  sequences adapted to the support of $i$? Because that way we would use the fact that $\Omega$ is Lipschitz domain

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but thinking about it again in Necas' inequality (depending on how you prove it) the boundary regularity comes in when you use the fact that the restriction $H^{-1}(\Bbb R^n) \rightarrow H^{-1}(\Omega)$ is continuous. This can be shown by duality and involves the existence of an extension operator $H^1(\Omega) \rightarrow H^1(\Bbb R^n).$ I've edited my answer slightly to include this.

Comment: I understand your explanation and my questions are around the utility of $\Omega$ is Lipschitz domain because I do not see clearly the use of this hypothesis. I think that we should generate a sequence as follows $f_\epsilon :=\theta_\epsilon(\rho_\epsilon * f)$ where $\theta_\epsilon$ is a partition of unity and $\rho_\epsilon$ is a standard mollifier.

Comment: If I understood your ideas. The use of partition of unity is to prove, by duality, that the extension by zero of $g$ belongs to $H^{-1}(\Omega) $